# Xcode plugin for improving code completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Recently I've done a small service [(available in Github)](https://github.com/emenegro/enum2switch) to return a switch case structure from a given `enum`.

The next step is to achieve this behaviour as an Xcode code completion option when I begin typing the enumeration name.

[image: Code completion]

What I want is to add a new option in this popup giving the possibility of generating a switch case with those three options.

I'm searching for documentation to make an Xcode plugin but I can't find much. My first question, and the most important is: is it possible to get the definition of a symbol while I'm typing it, to extract the data of the enum and generate the snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find a plugin that makes exactly what I wanted, [SCXcodeSwitchExpander](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCXcodeSwitchExpander). It works like a charm :D

Answer (score 7):

You can have a look at KSImageNamed, an XCode plug-in used to add autocompletion on image name.

You can inspire yourself on its code.

[KSImageNamed-Xcode](https://github.com/ksuther/KSImageNamed-Xcode)

Comment: Thank you, Gougou, I already knew that but it is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

an alternative to what you are suggesting is to save it as a code snippet. it wont be dynamic like you probably want it, but if you are using the same enum over and over, it can work.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Fonix but you are right, that isn't what I want. For now I'm using the service I linked before but as a code completion options it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Enumeration section here help?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150

It states that NS_ENUM "improves code completion".